# R: operator overloading  and Ops.zoo in zoo object

Tags: r, zoo

In R, how to implement operator overloading (like `+`, `-`, `*`, `./`) for a new class? I checked the source code of the zoo library, in `ops.R`. Does the following code do the job?

```
Ops.zoo <- function (e1, e2) 

{
    e <- if (missing(e2)) {
        NextMethod(.Generic)
    }
    else if (any(nchar(.Method) == 0)) {
        NextMethod(.Generic)
    }
    else {
    merge(e1, e2, all = FALSE, retclass = NULL)
        NextMethod(.Generic)
    }
    out <- if (is.null(attr(e, "index"))) 
    zoo(e, index(e1), attr(e1, "frequency"))
    else
    e
    # the next statement is a workaround for a bu g in R
    structure(out, class = class(out))
}
```

I am lost on the `merge(e1,e2,..)` block. I tested it with

```
 e1 <- zoo(rnorm(5), as.Date(paste(2003, 02, c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14), sep = "-")))
 e2 <- e1
 test <- merge(e1, e2, all = FALSE, retclass = NULL)
```

but then `test` is `NULL`. How does the `e <- {test; NextMethod(.Generic)}` work?

Comment: You could check `?Ops`. That and S3 methods should give you a handle on why this works.

Comment: @Nick,Thanks. I guess I need to study how merge.zoo(reclass=NULL) works to fully understand this.

Comment: is there a reason this is focused on `zoo`?  (see answer below).  Do you have a specific need to follow the format of `Ops.zoo` or is this just the example you were able to find?

Comment: PS if you don't need this to be about zoo, you might go back and modify the title to something like "operator overloading for arithmetic operators +,-,/,*"

Comment: That `merge` command writes its arguments back out in an aligned form so that they can be combined using ordinary operators.  It turns out that its slightly more efficient than returning them through the return value of the function since a single structure to hold them both does not have to be set up.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, thanks for the comments from the author. this and the answer from ben below enlightened me.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck - isn't `NextMethod()` sufficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may be looking at an example that is more complicated than necessary. It certainly seems worth reading `?Ops` (as the commenter above stated), but for basic examples you can do this pretty easily:

```
> `+.mychar` <- function(e1,e2) paste(e1,e2)
> x <- "a"
> y <- "b"
> class(x) <- "mychar"
> x+y
[1] "a b"
```

If something that simple doesn't suit your needs I would suggest (in addition to `?Ops`) looking at a simpler example like

```
`+.Date`
```

(note backward single quotes)